# ssis gpg encryption issues

Tags: ssis, gnupg

I have a SSIS package that uses Execute Process Task to encrypt file using gpg. Here are the arguments that I am using and its working perfectly fine from visual studio.
However when I deploy this package to SSISDB and run it, it says "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG directory does not exist".

```
Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe
Arguments : --batch --passphrase test -o "D:\test\file1.csv.gpg" -c "D:\test\file1.csv"
Working Directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG
```

I've also tried

```
Working Directory : D:\test (Or any other directory path)
```

When I run package from SSISDB- right click and validate then I get this error. my SQL server is running under NT Service\MSSQLSERVER account. (default, I haven't changed anything). I've granted admin permission to this account for C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG directory. What could be the reason for this and resolution?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use drive letters, the OS looks for the C:\ and D:\ drives on the local machine. When you run from VS/SSDT, that's *your* machine. When you run from SSISDB, that's the server.

Your best option would be to use (or create) a network installation of gpg.exe and a network share for your files, then reference them using UNC paths. Which you should code as project parameters and environment variables, against the day that those locations change, so you're not hunting through packages looking for those paths.

Another option is to put the artifacts that you need (pgp.exe and your files) onto drives on your server that are mapped identically to your local box. That's a maintenance nightmare over the long haul, but could be a quick fix for the immediate issue.